# When hover over img, all other images blur using CSS :not(:hover)

Tags: html, css, image, hover, blur

I'm trying to work out how to apply a blur effect on all other images when one image has been hovered:

```css
img:not(:hover) {
  filter: blur(3px);
  -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
  -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
  transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/All-the-fruits-that-day-were-poisend-.jpg" width="100px">

<img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/All-the-fruits-that-day-were-poisend-.jpg" width="100px">

<img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/All-the-fruits-that-day-were-poisend-.jpg" width="100px">
```

I was hoping that when no image is currently hovered all images would be rendered normally (i.e. without the blur effect). But this does not seem to be the case because at the moment, everything is blurred out.

How can I do achieve this effect with CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This trick works when you have a wrap element.

In this way you give the effect of all photos in the wrap except the one on which it is `:hover`

**CSS Short version:**

```css
#wrap img {
    -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
}

#wrap:hover img:not(:hover) {
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="100px">

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="100px">

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="100px">

</div>
```

---

**CSS Old-Style version:**

Do the same as above but with more CSS code

```css
#wrap img {
    -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
}

#wrap:hover img {
    filter: blur(3px);
}

#wrap img:hover {
    filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="100px">

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="100px">

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="100px">

</div>
```

---

**JS version 1:**

When there should be a wider distance between the objects, it is better to use JS

```js
var wrp = document.getElementById('wrap');
var img = wrp.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () { setEffect(this); });
    img[i].addEventListener("mouseout", resEffect);
};

function setEffect(el) {
    for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        img[i].setAttribute('style', 'filter: blur(3px);');
    };
    el.removeAttribute('style');
}

function resEffect() {
    for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        img[i].removeAttribute('style');
    };
}
```

```css
#wrap img {
    margin: 0 30px;

    -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="100px">

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="100px">

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="100px">

</div>
```

---

**JS version 2:**

Do the same as above "JS version 1", but retains the inline style on the image. This script preserves the default inline style of the images and adds the effect to it!

```js
var wrp = document.getElementById('wrap');
var img = wrp.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () { setEffect(this); });
    img[i].addEventListener("mouseout", resEffect);
};

function setEffect(el) {
    for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        img[i].style.filter = 'blur(3px)';
    };
    el.style.filter = null;
}

function resEffect() {
    for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        img[i].style.filter = null;
    };
}
```

```css
#wrap img {
    margin: 0 30px;

    -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="100px">

    <img style="border: 5px solid blue;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="100px">

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRK7bvAryKdY7JSlepTHatE1A4nAVU5lJXkdw&usqp=CAU"
        width="100px">

</div>
```

Comment: hey, the Javascript one works great, thanks ! But is there a way to do it, so it doesn't remove the existing style of the img? So it doesn't replace the whole styling associated with the img (just in terms of integrating it into my site), but just adds the blur filter on top of the existing css for img ?

Answer (score 0):

You may even incorporate javaScript code:-

1. Html

- adding `id` to all `img`

```html
<img id="1" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/All-the-fruits-that-day-were-poisend-.jpg" width="100px">

<img id="2" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/All-the-fruits-that-day-were-poisend-.jpg" width="100px">

<img id="3" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/All-the-fruits-that-day-were-poisend-.jpg" width="100px">
```

2. JavaScript

```js
(() => {
  let allImgElement = document.querySelectorAll('img')

  allImgElement.forEach(img => {
    // handle when mouse over (blurring other images)
    document.getElementById(img.id).addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      allImgElement.forEach(imgBlur => {
        if(imgBlur.id !== img.id) {
          document.getElementById(imgBlur.id).classList.add("imgBlur")
        }
      })
    })
  
    // handle when mouse out (unblur other images)
    document.getElementById(img.id).addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
      allImgElement.forEach(imgUnblur => {
        if(imgUnblur.id !== img.id) {
          document.getElementById(imgUnblur.id).classList.remove("imgBlur")
        }
      })
    })
  })
})()
```

3.Css

```
.imgBlur {
  
 filter: blur(3px);
 
 -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
 -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
 transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
}
```

```js
(() => {
let allImgElement = document.querySelectorAll('img')

allImgElement.forEach(img => {
    // handle when mouse over (blurring other images)
    document.getElementById(img.id).addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    allImgElement.forEach(imgBlur => {
      if(imgBlur.id !== img.id) {
        document.getElementById(imgBlur.id).classList.add("imgBlur")
      }
    })
  })
  
  // handle when mouse out (unblur other images)
  document.getElementById(img.id).addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    allImgElement.forEach(imgUnblur => {
      if(imgUnblur.id !== img.id) {
        document.getElementById(imgUnblur.id).classList.remove("imgBlur")
      }
    })
  })
})
})()
```

```css
.imgBlur {
  
 filter: blur(3px);
 
 -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
 -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
 transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
}
```

```html
<img id="1" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/All-the-fruits-that-day-were-poisend-.jpg" width="100px">

<img id="2" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/All-the-fruits-that-day-were-poisend-.jpg" width="100px">

<img id="3" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/All-the-fruits-that-day-were-poisend-.jpg" width="100px">
```